# Insert Column Lines on Android Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, user-interface

I am trying to insert vertical lines on an Android application and am having problems on how to do it.

My layout is currently designed as a Table and Row Layout which is already done.  Can anyone suggest  the best way to go about inserting the vertical lines on the layout that will span over several Table Row?  I cannot do a background color with spacing in between because the last are different colors and dashed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but will be try using this codes. such as

for horizontal line

```
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="#000000" />
```

for vertical line

```
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="#000000" />
```

Here you controls margin, padding dependable for your demands. Best of luck.